# CPU usage spikes when browsers are open

Tags: firefox, browser, firefox-extensions, htop

My Dell Latitude E6540 has been lagging and hanging with high CPU usage spikes without any load. Firefox regularly spikes with only few tabs open. Also even when switching to other browsers and in idle mode similar spikes appear. I've tried disabling and removing all extensions to no avail.
Occasionally, the performance returns to normal for a few minutes only to start spiking again. System Audio has significant glitches and noise artifacts during CPU spikes.

System details:

```
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS x86_64 
Host: Latitude E6540 00 
Kernel: 5.13.0-41-generic 
Uptime: 4 hours, 5 mins 
Packages: 3941 (dpkg), 38 (flatpak), 
Shell: zsh 5.8 
Resolution: 1920x1080 
DE: GNOME 
WM: Mutter 
WM Theme: Adwaita 
Theme: Adwaita-dark [GTK2/3] 
Icons: Yaru [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: x-terminal-emul 
CPU: Intel i7-4810MQ (8) @ 3.800GHz 
GPU: Intel 4th Gen Core Processor 
GPU: AMD ATI Radeon HD 8790M 
Memory: 2745MiB / 15907MiB
```

Link to [/var/log/syslog](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YHBp6--N_qm6M_TjrBTTOIcbjaFxsZud/view?usp=sharing)

Link to [New syslog](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zDzrKEtkaxrKqMFOa_PYmP--9w05Zke-/view?usp=sharing)

Results of `htop` :

[image: htop]

Update: Even after uninstalling and resinstalling firefox and all the other browsers spikes still persist, specially when playing media on youtube and others websites. Is there a way to profile the CPU usage during a spike and which part of the page or subprocess is hogging the CPU.

Update 2: I tried profiling Firefox Performance, here are the [results](https://share.firefox.dev/3bi0Ab9)

Comment: There are a lot [Media Controls](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4470/media-controls/) fails in syslog.
Are CPU usage spikes occur with disabled this Gnome extension?

Comment: @ExploitFate I tried what you said and it worked for a while. After rebooting the next morning the spikes are back again. I have attached new syslogs in the post.

Comment: Maybe Firefox' internal taks manager (`about:performance`) can give you a hint what's causing the problems. There, you can see what each AddOn and each currently open tab "consumes".

Comment: I did check firefox's task manager and found nothing unusual, have tried uninstalling and disabling firefox extensions to no improvement at all. Also I would like to point out that this is not a firefox exclusive issue, spikes occur with ALL browsers i have tried. As the firefox profiler results suggest this could be javascript problem as it shows quite a bit of "jank" whenever js interpreter kicks in.